# Adding a context menu only to the Expander header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to compose a data grid (in an MVVM 4.5 project) that will show my data grouped by a specific property (by use of expanders).  This all works but I'd like to add a context menu with the options "**Expand All**" and "**Collapse All**" which will collapse/expand all the groups. The event handlers for this menu item click events are being handled in the window's code-behind.

The problem is my context menu is applied to the expander and thus inherited by all its children which includes the `<ItemsPresenter/>` and this all rows/cells.

I want to *only* apply the context menu to the grouped header itself. This is achievable if it's applied to the innards (like the `StackPanel` in the example below) but in that case, the context menu isn't accessible for the entire Header line, only on the `StackPanel` contents/text.

I'm planning on using a different context menu for the items themselves (add/edit etc) and have a Collapse/Expand context menu only apply to the group header.  Is this achievable?

```
        <DataGrid Name="dgData" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">

            <DataGrid.Resources>

                <!--GroupHeader Text-->
                <Style x:Key="gridGroupTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </Style>

                <!--GroupHeader ContextMenu-->
                <ContextMenu x:Key="cm_columnHeaderMenu">
                    <MenuItem Name="mi_ExpandAll" Header="Expand groups"/>
                    <MenuItem Name="mi_CollapseAll" Header="Collapse groups"/>
                </ContextMenu>

                <!--Grouping style-->
                <Style x:Key="filesGroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="true">
                                    <Expander.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm_columnHeaderMenu}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Expander.Style>
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource gridGroupTextStyle}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text=" (" Style="{StaticResource gridGroupTextStyle}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Style="{StaticResource gridGroupTextStyle}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text=")" Style="{StaticResource gridGroupTextStyle}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource filesGroupHeaderStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding Prop1}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding Prop2}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" Binding="{Binding Prop3}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>                

        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you right, you want to click anywhere in your `StackPanel` and get the `ContextMenu` to work like this:

[image: ContextMenu]

If yes, here we go in code:

```
 <Expander Grid.Row="1">
            <Expander.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Style>
            </Expander.Style>
            <Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}}" Background="Pink" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel" >
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu"  Value="{StaticResource cm_columnHeaderMenu}"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                    <TextBlock Text="world" />
                    <TextBlock Text=")" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Dummy"></TextBlock>
        </Expander>
```

What did i do?

- First, bind your Stackpanel-Width to actual width of Expander
- Second, make the Stackpanel stretch.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hang on... you can FIND ANCESTOR?! I am amaze :D
Was trying to do something like that for ages!

Comment: Heads up on this solution:  I set the databound width to the DataGrid ancestor instead of the Expander. There was a massive performance drop when binding to the Expander's width which sort of makes sense due to the number of grouped elements.